# How can I rename my c# namespace to include a dot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, refactoring

I want to rename my namespace, `MyProjectTest.Core` to `MyProject.Test.Core`, but the Visual Studio 2017 refactoring tool doesn't let me insert `.` into the name.

I do not want to do that manually, is there another option?

Comment: what you mean it doesn't let you insert `.`? You can rename namespace and add as many `.`s as you want.

Comment: As is only apparent in the answer (but ought to be in the *question*), this appears to specifically be talking about performing a rename via the Refactoring tool.

Answer (score 18):

It is correct, you can not use your keyboard key `.` to enter a dot, however, you can use `CTRL`+`C` to copy the dot character (from this answer, if you want) and then insert the dot into the name with `CTRL`+`V`.

Note: Visual Studio 2017 will complain about invalid characters, but it will rename it anyway if you click apply:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 complaining about the invalid character 1]
[image: Visual Studio 2017 complaining about the invalid character 2]

Comment: How could I do if I want to change from "My.Project" to "My.Project.Core", for example.
When I select "My.Project" then crtl + r + crtl + r to rename the ide just select "My"

Comment: Be careful with such renames since it could lead to unexpected changes. E. g. renaming of `MyProject` part in `MyProject.Test.Core` will rename all instances of all namespaces started with `MyProject`, not only `MyProject.Test.Core`. And adding a dot to the new name will make undo quite hard.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2022, but still works in VS2019, great answer.

Answer (score -1):

Goto project properties and change the default namespace.

Comment: Your answer looks either incomplete because you mean doing this in combination with the "Sync namespaces" action on the project (moreover I doubt it exists in VS 2017) or wrong because changing the default namespace of the project alone will only affect files generated after the change and not existing files. I suggest that you either edit to add more details or simply delete your answer